# Get current date as mm/dd/yyyy in php using strftime() because setlocale() is used

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am using:

```
strftime("%m/%d/%Y", date())
```

But it gives:

```
12/31/1969
```

I want current date like `mm/dd/yyyy`

Edit:

Can I get current date using strftime? because the code has setlocale() used

Comment: `echo date('m/d/Y')` perhaps?

Comment: Please use the search. Normally works even faster than asking a question. Even in case not: It's required, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - Also first and foremost your question code gives: *"Warning: date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given"*, a simple `strftime("%m/%d/%Y");` would have done it: https://eval.in/159678

Comment: Edit: Yes you can. I already edited the so far most correct answer showing how it works. Perhaps refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want such format:

```
echo strftime("%m/%d/%Y"); // 06/07/2014
```

or the [**date**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) Function

```
echo date('m/d/Y'); // 06/07/2014
```

or the [**DateTime**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) Class

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); // 06/07/2014
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date` like this

```
$data = date('m/d/Y');
```

You were attempting to use mysql-style date formatting. As you observed, that didn't work.

Comment: -1: Wrong explanation shipping in this answer (which for the rest is an uber-dupe): See http://php.net/strftime